# Invalid shorthand property initializer with a variable int

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

when I run my code, I get the following error:

Invalid shorthand property initializer.

```js
function DisplyayNote() {
    let noteId = -1;
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

    return isOpen ? (
        {noteId = 0 ? <div className="backComponent">
        <div className="noteOpen">
            <div>C'est ouvert</div>
            <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>Fermer</button>
        </div>
    </div> : null}
    ) : (
        <>
            <div>C'est fermé</div>
            <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>Ouvrir</button>
        </>
    );
}
```

Would you have an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: That's not the error that is produced by the code you are showing here. Here you get `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'"`.  You can't just include raw HTML within JavaScript so when the JS runtime encounters the beginning of some markup, which starts with `<`, you get the error.

Comment: Curly braces are only necessary inside of a jsx expression. In your snippet, the jsx expression isn't started yet but you have wrapped the parent ternary inside curly braces, which is then treated as an object literal.

Comment: @ScottMarcus that's JSX, not HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is no need to add `{`. Second, change `note_id=0` to `note_id==0` or `note_id===0` because `note_id=0` is not a boolean expression. I have used the code snippet below to test it and its working fine.

```
function DisplyayNote() {
    let noteId = 0;
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

    return isOpen ? (

        noteId == 0 ? <div className="backComponent">
            < div className="noteOpen" >
                <div>C'est ouvert</div>
                <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>Fermer</button>
            </div >
        </div > : null

    ) : (
        <>
            <div>C'est fermé</div>
            <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>Ouvrir</button>
        </>
    );
};
```

[image: working image]

Answer (score -1):

Please change `noteId = 0` to `noteId === 0`

Comment: I have this error : Unexpected token, expected ","

Answer (score -1):

In short, it was enough to put everything in a container:

```js
return isOpen ? (
        <>
        {noteId >= 0 ?
            <div className="backComponent">
                <div className="noteOpen">
                 <div>C'est ouvert</div>
                     <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>Fermer</button>
                </div>
            </div> : null}
        </>
    ) : (
        <>
            <div>C'est fermé</div>
            <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>Ouvrir</button>
        </>
    );
```

Comment: `isOpen ? (noteId >= 0` without the curly brace `{` would have been enough.